# Need to find maximum in order to prove that the function converges uniformly.

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

So, here is the function: $f_n = \sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x}\right)$
I found that the limit for it is $0$. Now I want to show whether it converges uniformly. So first I tried to find a maximum.
$$f'_n(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) = \\ \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}}\right)$$

Then I solve for the x at denominator.
$$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}=0 \Rightarrow x -2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}+x+\frac{1}{n}= 0 \\ 2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{{x+\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{n}+2x \Rightarrow 2x^2+2x\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n^2}+4x\frac{1}{n}+4x^2 \\ 2x^2+2x\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}=0 \ \ x_1 = \frac{-2\frac{1}{n}+ \sqrt{\frac{4}{n^2}-\frac{8}{n^2}}}{6} = -\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n}=0$$
$$x_2 = -\frac{2}{3n}$$
I get very clumsy $x_1$ so I gather I have made some mistake all along. Can someone help?

Comment: After you squared both sides in the third step, it should be $x -2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}+x+\frac{1}{n}= 0$, not $x +2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}+x+\frac{1}{n}= 0$.  Also following the first mistake, the $-2x$ should be $+2x$ and when you squared both sides for a second time you forgot to square the $2$.

Comment: Is $f_n$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ or some subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Ty. Is it now correct?

Comment: @devianceee $Df \in (0, \infty)$

Comment: @user67 Not quite, in the second to last line you didn't square the 2 in $2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{{x+\frac{1}{n}}}$.  It should be $4x^2+4x\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Ty. Ok, yes, but then I cannot even express $x$ as everything cancels out and $\frac{1}{n^2}=0$, which cannot be true.

Comment: Yeah, the algebra is correct when you get that.  I'm assuming this is real analysis which I am not familiar with.  You can't check for convergence with the derivative I suppose.  Check other answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence of functions converges pointwise to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$. Thus, it converges uniformly to zero if $||f_n||_{\infty}= \sup_{x}|f_n(x)| \to 0$. But $f_n(x) \to 1$ as $x \to 0$, so $||f_n||_{\infty}\geqslant 1$ for all $n$ and $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly

Comment: Ok, I was just checking for derivatives.

Comment: Your calculations do not make sense. As the square root function is injective, there is no $x$ such that $\sqrt{x + \frac{1}{n}} = \sqrt{x}$!

Comment: Moreover, next time you have $\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} = 0$, I suggest you not to square this quantity, but to write $\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{b}$, and then square it: it gives you directly $a=b$. You did a much harder calculation

Comment: @Dldier_ I don't understand why max value should tend to 0? Also the function tends to zero as $n $ tends to infinity, then what is the reason you look for limit as x tends to zero?

Comment: Your main question is "is the sequence converging uniformly" right ? The definition of uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f$ is that $||f_n-f||_{\infty} \to 0$ whith $n$. Here, $f=0$. So the claim "$(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f=0$" is equivalent to "$\|f_n\|_{\infty}\to 0$ with $n$". Which is then equivalent to "$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^*_+} |f_n(x)| \to 0$". But as this supremum is always bigger than $1$ (because you can find some $x>0$ such that $f_n(x)$ is close to $1$, as $f_n(x) \to 1$ when $x \to 0$), the claim is false.